# Find rows with two or more relationships 

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 3 tables:

`Foods` table stores all food items, `Tags` table stores all tags, `FoodTagRelation` stores the relation between food and tags. I want to write a query to select all Food that have exactly 2 tags with `specified Ids` **(please read the SQL I have written at the bottom**)

```
Foods Table

Id | FoodItem
----------------------
1  | Mango
2  | Custard
3  | Pizza

Tags Table

Id | TagName 
----------------------
1  |  Fruit
2  |  Cold
3  |  Hot
4  |  Veg

FoodTagRelation 

Id | FoodId | TagId
----------------------
1  | 1      | 1
2  | 1      | 4
3  | 2      | 1
4  | 2      | 2
5  | 2      | 4
```

Now I want to select all foods that have exactly two tags on it: e.g. select all foods which have both tags: `Fruit` and `Cold`.

I tried this query, but it returns all food with tags `Fruit` **OR** `Cold`.

```
select * from Foods
 inner join FoodTagRelation
 on
 Foods.Id=FoodTagRelation.FoodId
 where
 tagid in ('1','2')
```

How can I re-write this query to only return foods that have **BOTH** tags?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a more generic answer that allows you to change the tags for which you're searching:

```
DECLARE @Search_Tags TABLE (TagId INT)

INSERT INTO @Search_Tags (TagId) VALUES (1), (2)

SELECT
    F.Id,
    F.FoodItem
FROM
    Foods F
INNER JOIN FoodTagRelation FTR ON
    FTR.FoodId = F.Id
INNER JOIN @Search_Tags ST ON
    ST.TagId = FTR.TagId
GROUP BY
    F.Id,
    F.FoodItem
HAVING
    COUNT(*) = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @Search_Tags)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
   F.id,
   F.FoodItem
FROM
   Foods F
   INNER JOIN FoodTagRelation FTR
   ON F.Id = FTR.FoodId
WHERE
   FTR.tagid in('1','2')
GROUP BY
   F.id,
   F.FoodItem
HAVING
   count(Distinct FTR.tagid) > 1
```

Features: uses count distinct, to prevent an issue with duplicate tagid's for a given FoodID in your FoodTagRelation table.  (If you don't think that duplicates are a concern, then you can remove the 'distinct' keyword).  Secondly, I kept your WHERE clause, because that allows you to look for **specific** tags, as opposed to just *any two*.  Finally, I listed out your fields, because that was necessary in order to use the group by clause (which in turn, was necessary in order to use the HAVING clause.)

Answer (score 0):

do a group by on FoodID and use having count(tagID) = 2

```
select *
from foods as f inner join foodtagrelation as ftr on f.id=ftr.foodid
where (ftr.tagid = 1 or ftr.tagid = 2)
group by f.foodid
having count(*) = 2
```

Comment: i have edited the question to be make it more informative.  As you have missed the clause `tagid in ('1','2')`, look the sql i ahve written at the bottom.

Comment: @Rusi.. I added the additional conditions.  You will find that for only a couple of values, that you may get better performance using an or clause rather than the in clause.

Answer (score 0):

When you said "select all Food which **exactly** 2 tags", if a food have 3 tag which include Fruit and Cold and some other tag. Does it count?

Anyway, here is query to find food that have both Fruit and Cold.

```
SELECT * 
FROM Foods f
INNER JOIN FoodTagRelation ft1
 ON f.Id=ft1.FoodId
INNER JOIN FoodTagRelation ft2
 ON f.Id=ft2.FoodId 
WHERE
 ft1.tagid = 1 AND  ft2.tagid = 2
```

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT * from Foods where FoodId in (
select FoodID from FoodTagRelation  where TagId in (1,2) 
group by FoodId having count(*)=2
)
```

**NOTE** Updating my SQL because the Rusi seems to only care about Foods with exactly to tags where TagId is (1 or 2)

Comment: i have edited the question to be make it more informative.  As you have missed the clause `tagid in ('1','2')`, look the sql i ahve written at the bottom.

Comment: @Rusi Nova: Updated my answer. Now you'll only get foods with exactly 2 tags for tags 1 or 2.